# How to slow-down brute-force attacks against LUKS without slowing down the LUKS performance?

Tags: luks

https://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/hardening-generic-luks-from-common-distro-installs.389776/

```
 sudo cryptsetup-reencrypt /dev/sda3 -c twofish-xts-plain64 -s 512 -h sha512 -i 9000
```

**Question**: but is there a way to massively slow-down the brute-force attacks against the LUKS password, while keeping the LUKS performance?

Comment: crank up the iteration count, `--iter-time`. Opening the container takes longer, but once open the performance is unchanged

Comment: can you please post this as answer?

Comment: @frostschutz: can you please post that increasing the iteration slows down an attacker, but not the io?

Answer (score 1):

See https://linux.die.net/man/8/cryptsetup , section --timeout -t

> The number of seconds to wait before timeout. This option is relevant every time a password is asked, like create, luksOpen, luksFormat or luksAddKey.

This has no affect on the performance in general. This will only increase or decrease the waiting time when given a wrong pass phrase.

Comment: This only affects password guessing attempts made on pepite's installation, not attempts made by plugging the disk on another machine, which is the actual threat here. (Attempts made on pepite's installation are limited by the rate at which someone can type on the keyboard.)